# Django: How do I redirect to page where form originated

Tags: python, django

In my Django app I have multiple pages displaying a link that loads a new page displaying a form. When the form is submitted, what is the cleanest way to redirect to the originating page from which this form was accessed?

**originating page -> form page -> originating page**

Using a next variable seems unellegant since I have to set it as a GET variable on the originating page link, and then set it as a hidden POST variable in my form? Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of options, all with the cons and benefits ofcourse.

1. passing the originating page withi `POST`/`GET`
2. storing the originating page in the session (won't work with multiple tabs obviously)
3. storing the originating page in a cookie (won't work with multiple tabs either)
4. if it's a single page, redirect to the referrer. Doesn't seem possible in your case

Personally I think using a next parameter is your best option, but do remember to secure it (only relative urls, no javascript stuff, csrf framework) so you won't have any security problems with it.

Comment: Thanks WoLpH and Tomasz for great explanation. I stuck with option 1 then.

Answer (score 7):

**WoLpH** already listed the resonable possibilities and pointed to (probably) the best of them as a solution. So I will only elaborate on it.

If you need to handle this: **originating page -> form page -> originating page** then in reality it will look like this: **originating page --[GET]--> form page --[POST/submision]--> form page(2) --[GET/redirect]--> originating page**. This means, that **form page(2)** stage has to somehow know where to redirect user and the only reasonable choices you have here is to use session (with the drawback mentioned by **WoLpH**) or to pass it in POST, possibly as a hidden field.

Regarding the first GET and passing `next URL` into **form page**, you can either pass it in the query string (which you find unelegant), or you can extract it from HTTP_REFERER header - which won't work for more paranoid users like me.

You can also do a mixed stuff here, i.e. add `next=<next-URL>` into the query string *if and only if* user hasn't turned off HTTP_REFERER in her browser. Then most users won't see any ugly stuff in URLs.

Note that all these things can be automated, i.e. you can write your links as:

```
<a href="{% url myform %}?{% inject_next_url %}">
```

When `inject_next_url` injects sth like: `next={{ context['request'].get_full_path() }}` only if HTTP_REFERER is not present.

Then, in form handler you can use some generic `extract_next_url(request)` function, that looks for `next URL` in one of: query string, HTTP_REFERER, request.POST, or more consise - in one of: HTTP_REFERER, request.REQUEST

Comment: Great explanation, +1
Nice to hear that I'm not the only one that's paranoid enough to block his referrer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to create separate URL conf that resolve to the same view, and passing in the source view as a kwargs to the view.