# Redirecting user from regstration page to original page in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am fairly new to Django and am looking to do the following in Django framework:

1. Note: I do not have questions about this one, since the solutions have been already presented on SO.
   If user is not logged in redirect them to the login page and after successful login redirect back to the original page.
2. This is where I do not know how to implement it:
   While on the login page, the user should be able to click on "register" and be redirected to the registration page. After successful registration, I would like them to be automatically logged in and be redirected to the original page.

So the sequence might look like that.

Original page -> login page -> registration page -> Original page

How do  keep track of original page while being on registration page?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203417/django-how-do-i-redirect-to-page-where-form-originated

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am just curious, if you happen to know, when they say: "using GET variable", like: "originating page --[GET]--> form page", how is GET supposed to work here? Does it mean I can attach a "GET" variable to the request without a form and then get it in the "form page"? How s it done?

Comment: Correct. In the thread I mentioned the last post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4204263/559095) describes that method using a "next" url param. Such as http://abc?next=xyz